# I am attempting to append a form by adding extra rows with Text fields, number fields, and select fields

Tags: append, html-table, rows

my objective was to have a code to insert formatted rows into a table (clone the table I designed) I have a code which works but will not accept the select field.

This code works but will not accept the select field with the preset information in the code.
            
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("form").append("Field Name:Field Name:Field Name:");
            });
        });

So I searched and found this dose which looks better but I can not get to work.

```
c.append( 
    $('<form>', {
         method : 'POST',
         action : ''
    }).append( 
        $('<select />', {
            name : 'retour'
        }).append(
            $('<option />', {text : 'option1'}),
            $('<option />', {text : 'option2'}),
            $('<option />', {text : 'option3'}),
            $('<option />', {text : 'option4'}),
            $('<option />', {text : 'option5'})
        )
    )
);
```

which i modified to:

```
<body>
<p>Click the button below to dynamically add more fields</p>
<form>
<form id="Test" name="Test" method="post">
<table>
<tr>
<td>Number:</td>
<td><input type="number"></td>
<td>Field Name:</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td>Field Name:</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><label for="select">Select:</label></td>
<td><select name="select" id="select">
  <option value="50" selected>50</option>
  <option value="100">100</option>
</select></td>
<td>Field Name:</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
<td>Field Name:</td>
<td><input type="text"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<button>Add Fields</button>

<script>
    $("button").click(function(){
        $('<form>',{
            method : 'POST', 
            id : 'Test'
            }).append(
            $('table'),
                $('<tr>'),
                $('<td>Number:</td>'),
                $('<td><input type="number"></td>'),
                $('<td>Field Name:</td>'),
                $('<td><input type="text"></td>'),
                $('<td>Field Name:</td>'),
                $('<td><input type="text"></td></tr>'),
                $('<tr>'),
                $('<td><label for="select">Select:</label></td>'),
                $('<td><select name="select" id="select">'),
                $('<option value="50" selected>50</option>'),
                $('<option value="100">100</option>'),
                $('</select></td>'),
                $('<td>Field Name:</td>'),
                $('<td><input type="text"></td>'),
                $('<td>Field Name:</td>'),
                $('<td><input type="text"></td>'),
                $('</tr>')
                )
        });
</script>

</body>
</html>.
```

and I just keep hitting a wall.
any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT :
use this code i tried it and it works :

```
   $("#button").click(function(){  $("body:last").after('<form id="Test" name="Test" method="post"><select  name="select" id="select"><option value="50" selected>50</option><option value="100">100</option></select></form>');
     });
```